# How to wait until BackgroundWorker finish all calls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `Add button click event` how add file:

```
private void btnAddfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            System.IO.Stream stream;
            try
            {
                if ((stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (stream)
                    {
                        StartBackgroundFileChecker(file);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

every file that i am pass to `StartBackgroundFileChecker(string file)` need to open process and check this file before add to my `ListBox` so i am doing this via `BackgroundWorker` in order to prevent my GUi to freeze and all work perfect:

```
private void StartBackgroundFileChecker(string file)
{            
    ListboxFile listboxFile = new ListboxFile();
    listboxFile.OnFileAddEvent += listboxFile_OnFileAddEvent;
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        //check my file via another class
    };

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        ///
    });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

when i am finish to read all my files i want to update my UI so if i put this Ui update inside `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted...` it update my UI after every call to this function and i am looking for way to do it at the end of all calls

Comment: Do you need every file to run in its own `BackgroundWorker` ?

Comment: IMO BackgroundWorker is not the right tool for this job. Parallel.Foreach may be more suitable here.

Comment: The simple solution is to put the foreach loop in the worker instead.  And have it generate a List<> with "good" files, one you then use in RunWorkerCompleted to update your UI.

Comment: `Parallel.Foreach` would block the UI thread.

Comment: @Ahmed KRAIEM, no, only after all the files finished

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Tasks then :)

Comment: @Rotem, can you show me code example ?

Comment: @Rotem, won't the Parallel.ForEach run on the UI Thread thus locking up his UI?

Comment: @Brad Yes, but using an array of Tasks should work. Can't write a full example at the moment but basically fire up `Task`s in a loop, store them in an list, and call `Task.WhenAll` to run code when they all finish. Hans' idea sounds much simpler though.

Comment: @Rotem: Tasks.WhenAll only available in 4.5

Comment: @YK Ah didn't realize that. Listen to Hans then, always a good idea :)

Comment: @user2214609 I've edited my answer since I've previously misunderstood you. Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most easy way is to keep a counter.

```
private int numWorkers = 0;
```

Then increment it as you start each background worker.

```
using (stream)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref numWorkers);
    StartBackgroundFileChecker(file);
}
```

Assign *Same* method as event completed to each background worker.

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += myCommonCompletedHandler;
```

Decrement counter in completed event.

```
public void myCommonCompletedHandler(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref numWorkers) == 0) 
    {
      // all complete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this approch with only one `BackgroundWorker`.

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

private void btnAddfiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            StartBackgroundFileChecker(openFileDialog1.FileNames);   
        };

        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged +=
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            //example:
            this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        };

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            ///End Here!!
        });

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
private void StartBackgroundFileChecker(string[] files)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        string file = files[i];
        System.IO.Stream stream;
        try
        {
            if ((stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (stream)
                {
                    ListboxFile listboxFile = new ListboxFile();
                    listboxFile.OnFileAddEvent += listboxFile_OnFileAddEvent;
                    //Other things...
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((i+1) * 100.0/files.Length, file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem, this worked for me.

```
 private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Worker.IsBusy == false) { //...Finished execution }
    }
```